# How can I change double type to integer type in unix?

Tags: awk

I have this awk command.

```
awk '{t1=$1/5;t2=$2/5;t3=$3/5} END{print t1" "t2" "t3}' temp1 > temp3
```

I want to change the data type of the t1 value into integer. How can I do that?

Regards

Soe

Answer (score 2):

Simply specify that `t1` should be formatted as an integer:

```
awk '{t1=$1/5;t2=$2/5;t3=$3/5} END{printf "%d %.6g %.6g\n", t1, t2, t3}' temp1 > temp3
```

The `%.6g` is the default format (also held in OFMT).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `int()` function on the `t1` value:

```
int(t1)
```

It truncates the decimals, leaving only the integer part of the value.